# Jekyll Collections - Skip index page

Tags: jekyll

I have the below folder structure in my Jekyll site:

```
...
_machine-learning
|- my-first-post.md
|- index.html 
...
```

I wanted to arrange my site, such that when someone visits `http://example.com/machine-learning/`, they can see all of the collection pages neatly listed.

To do that, I added the following to my `index.html`:

```
<h1 class="page-heading">Machine Learning</h1>

<ul class="post-list">
  {% for item in site.machine-learning %}
    <a href="{{ item.url | prepend: item.baseurl }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This works fine, but the only issue is that it displays my `index.html` in there as well, making everything look like a mess.

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I iterate through my collection, skipping over index?

Comment: The idea is to reproduce your problem. Give a repository url and clarify **making everything look like a mess** because it means nothing with a context.

Comment: thanks for chiming in David. Turns out this is expected behavior, so closing this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed the folder structure, moving the `index.html` file from inside the `machine-learning/` collection to the root folder as `machine-learning.html`. The URL remains the same (example.com/machine-learning) and it doesn't show up in the `site.machine-learning` list.

Before:

```
...
_machine-learning
|- my-first-post.md
|- index.html 
...
```

After:

```
...
machine-learning.html
_machine-learning
|- my-first-post.md
...
```